# Inbound connections to a ubuntu machine running a VPN

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn

Is it possible to open inbound connections to a machine connected to a VPN server?

The machine is running ubuntu 9.10 with two network devices(a wireless card and ethernet port), I can connect to my machine locally using a local ip but when I try port forward using my router I can't connect from my external ip.

Is there a way around this? I figure with 2 network devices I can vpn over one and use the other for inbound connections but I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a common practice for VPN software to change the client computer's routing table and set the VPN interface as the default gateway. I think the reasoning behind this is to add an extra bit of security, so the data coming in through the LAN interface would not get into VPN channel. So, this is actually a good thing.

If you still want to change this behavior, check your default gateway using `route` command and, if it's set to the VPN interface, try to find relevant settings in your VPN client.

In some cases, though, it can only be changed on the server.

You might also want to thumb through [this old discussion on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vpnc/+bug/124663)